# Can I build a java class in jdk14 but use java 11 for my own library?

Tags: java, maven

My library (using maven/java 11) has a dependency to a class in another library which used java 14 to compile the class.

So to build the dependency, I need to use java 14, but I don't want consumers of my library to have to be forced to upgrade to java 14. The class I'm dependent on is a simple domain class that doesn't use any java 14 features.

Is this possible? Or would I need to bump to java 14 in my own library?

Comment: If it's a runtime dependency, then you'll force consumers of your class to also depend on the external library and thus run Java 14. You can either re-compile your dependency with Java 11 or copy the source into your library and get rid of the dependency.

Comment: If you're going to bump anyhow, bump to a LTS build like Java 17. Overall though, outside of recompiling the dependency, older code cannot depend on newer code.

Comment: In general your consumers must use JDK14+ but as you described that the dependend project does not use JDK14 it is needed to rebuild that with JDK11 and released. So you can drop down your minimum requirement. Assumed that you have control over the other project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to depend on a third part lib that uses java14, your project must use at least java14.

If you can rebuild and distribute a custom version of the third party lib @ java11, you can keep your project at java11.

I highly recommend only sticking on LTS versions of Java: 7,8,11,17 as this makes it much easier for the ecosystem to use your code and build it. Java14 is already sunset.

Comment: And so if I use java 14 in my own library, subsequently any consumers of my library now also need to bump to java 14+. And so it's essentially a chain reaction right?

Comment: I do have control over potentially changing code in the external library. So wondering maybe the best approach here is to drop to java 11 for the module I depend on; and then my own library doesn't need to go out of java 11

Comment: > And so if I use java 14 in my own library, subsequently any consumers of my library now also need to bump to java 14+. And so it's essentially a chain reaction right?

That's correct

Comment: I think the best course of action is to make the third party module java11 or java17 compatible, and adopt java11 or java17 for your project accordingly.

Comment: makes sense. This is helpful thanks! I will try to adopt java11 in 3rd party module. If not the best course of action is probably to copy/paste code and just remove the dependency to the library entirely.